# Summing the number of occurrences from m/d/y to y/m

Tags: r

I have data of from each of the avalanches that occurred. I need to calculate the number of avalanches that occurred by each year and month but the data just gives the exact days that an avalanche occurred. How do I sum the number of occurrences that occurred during each year-month? I also only need the winter related year-months (Dec (12) - March (3)). Please help!

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(dplyr)
avalanche<-data.frame()
avalanche.url<-"https://utahavalanchecenter.org/observations?page="
all.pages<-0:202
for(page in all.pages){
  this.url<-paste(avalanche.url, page, sep="")
  this.webpage<-htmlParse(getURL(this.url))
  thispage.avalanche<-readHTMLTable(this.webpage, which=1, header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
  names(thispage.avalanche)<-c('Date','Region','Location','Observer')
  avalanche<-rbind(avalanche,thispage.avalanche)
}

# subset the data to the Salt Lake Region
avalancheslc<-subset(avalanche, Region=="Salt Lake")
str(avalancheslc)
```

The output should look something like:

```
Date       AvalancheTotal
2000-01           1
2000-02           2
2000-03           8
2000-12           23
2001-01           16
.
.
.
.
.
2019-03            45
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to `yearmon` from `zoo` and use that in the group_by to get the number of rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

dim(avalancheslc)
#[1] 5494    4
out <- avalancheslc %>% 
          group_by(Date = format(as.yearmon(Date, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y-%m")) %>% 
          summarise(AvalancheTotal = n())
```

If we need only output from `December` to `March`, then `filter` the data

```
subOut <- out %>%
            filter(as.integer(substr(Date, 6, 7)) %in% c(12, 1:3))
```

---

Or it can be `filter`ed earlier in the chain

```
library(lubridate)
out <- avalancheslc %>%
         mutate(Date = as.yearmon(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
         filter(month(Date) %in% c(12, 1:3))  %>% 
         count(Date)
dim(out)
#[1] 67  2
```

Now, for filling with 0's

```
mths <- month.abb[c(12, 1:3)]
out1 <- crossing(Months = mths, 
            Year = year(min(out$Date)):year(max(out$Date))) %>%
       unite(Date, Months, Year, sep= " ") %>% 
       mutate(Date = as.yearmon(Date)) %>% 
       left_join(out) %>% 
       mutate(n = replace_na(n, 0)) 

tail(out1)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  Date              n
#  <S3: yearmon> <dbl>
#1 Mar 2014        100
#2 Mar 2015         94
#3 Mar 2016         96
#4 Mar 2017         93
#5 Mar 2018        126
#6 Mar 2019        163
```

Comment: This works but how can I have it only include Dec-Mar of each year? Also, if there are no values for Dec, Jan, Feb, or Mar for a year...how can I have it =0?

Comment: @crich If you look at the `subOut`, it is filtering from 'Dec-Mar

Comment: subOut works! Now, I need to add dates within the Dec-Mar range that have no avalanches...how can I add these missing dates with 0 avalanches

Comment: How can I fill in the missing dates between all these records for subOut? Some year-months have no avalanches. For example, 1980-01 had 1 avalanche but the next data point is not until 1981-02. How can I fill in 1980-02, 1980-03, 1980-12, etc with their respective date and "O" under the AvalancheTotal? I want to keep the format of year-month so I can merge it with another data set that has a year-month  variable

Comment: @crich Please check the 'out1'  instead of 'subOut'.  It is filled

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr, you could get the variable of interest ("year-month") from the Date column, group by this variable, and then compute the number of rows in each group. 
In a similar way, you can filter to only get the months you like:

```
library(dplyr)
winter_months <- c(1:3, 12)

avalancheslc %>% 
    mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>% 
    mutate(YearMonth = format(Date,"%Y-%m"), 
           Month = as.numeric(format(Date,"%m"))) %>%
    filter(Month %in% winter_months) %>%
    group_by(YearMonth) %>%
    summarise(AvalancheTotal = n())
```

Comment: How can I fill in the missing dates between all these records? Some year-months have no avalanches. For example, 1980-01 had 1 avalanche but the next data point is not until 1981-02. How can I fill in 1980-02, 1980-03, 1980-12, etc with their respective date and "O" under the AvalancheTotal?

Comment: Create another data frame listing *all* months you want in your output, left join the output data frame to it, and replace NA values with 0?